# trait implementation

Tags: scala, traits

If I have some traits like:

```
trait A {...}
trait B extends A{...}
trait C1 extends B{...}
trait C2 extends A{...}
```

I can write class in two ways (C1 and C2 add same functionality)

```
class Concrete1 extends B with C1
class Concrete2 extends B with C2
```

What variant is better(efficient)?

Comment: If C1 and C2 add the same functionality why are they separate?

Comment: Runtime efficiency for method invocation?  Programmer efficiency for readability?

Comment: @Mitch Blevins Runtime efficiency for method invocation (and I'm thinking about Concrete{1,2} instantiation time)
@Difference in inheritance - thay extends different classes but have same f functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are identical in terms of performance.  If you write a test like this:

```
object Traits {
  trait A { def a = "apple" }
  trait B extends A { def b = "blueberry" }
  trait C1 extends B { def c = "cherry" }
  trait C2 extends A { def c = "chard" }
  class Dessert extends B with C1 { }
  class Salad extends B with C2 { }
}
```

and look at the bytecode for `Dessert` and `Salad` you see

```
public Traits$Dessert();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #29; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   invokestatic    #33; //Method Traits$A$class.$init$:(LTraits$A;)V
   8:   aload_0
   9:   invokestatic    #36; //Method Traits$B$class.$init$:(LTraits$B;)V
   12:  aload_0
   13:  invokestatic    #39; //Method Traits$C1$class.$init$:(LTraits$C1;)V
   16:  return

public Traits$Salad();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #29; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   invokestatic    #33; //Method Traits$A$class.$init$:(LTraits$A;)V
   8:   aload_0
   9:   invokestatic    #36; //Method Traits$B$class.$init$:(LTraits$B;)V
   12:  aload_0
   13:  invokestatic    #39; //Method Traits$C2$class.$init$:(LTraits$C2;)V
   16:  return
```

If you then go and look at the initializers for `C1` and `C2`, they're both empty.  If you look at the method call for `c`, again, it's a reference to the one defined either in `C1` or `C2`.

This happens because of the way layered traits are interpreted.  You can think of them as a stack: each time you add a "with", the whole inheritance hierarchy is pushed onto the stack *except* that anything already there is not added again.  So it doesn't matter whether `C2` has `B` or not, since the class `Salad` already picked up `B` because it extends `B`.